# Changing styles when selecting and deselecting multiple polygons with Leaflet/Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, selection

I'm having some problems changing polygon styles when selecting and deselecting polygons in a Leaflet Shiny app I'm working on. In my current app, when you click on a polygon, that polygon is highlighted with a different color. Ideally, I want the user to be able to select and highlight multiple polygons. I also want the user to be able to re-click a single highlighted polygon to deselect it.

The best that I've been able to manage is to select multiple polygons, give them the same group ID "selected", then deselect that entire group when a polygon is re-clicked. Here's some example/reproducible code:

```
library(raster)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

#load shapefile
rwa <- getData("GADM", country = "RWA", level = 1)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("map")
  ), 

  server <- function(input, output, session){

    #initial map output
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addPolygons(data = rwa, 
                    fillColor = "white", 
                    fillOpacity = 1, 
                    color = "black", 
                    stroke = T, 
                    weight = 1, 
                    layerId = rwa@data$OBJECTID, 
                    group = "regions")
    }) #END RENDER LEAFLET

    observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {

      #create object for clicked polygon
      click <- input$map_shape_click

      #define leaflet proxy for second regional level map
      proxy <- leafletProxy("map")

      #subset regions shapefile by the clicked on polygons
      selectedReg <-rwa[rwa@data$OBJECTID == click$id,]


      #map clicked on polygons
      proxy %>% addPolygons(data = selectedReg,
                            fillColor = "red",
                            fillOpacity = 1,
                            weight = 1,
                            color = "black", 
                            stroke = T,
                            group = "selected",
                            # layerId = "selected")
                            layerId = selectedReg@data$OBJECTID)


      #remove polygon group that are clicked twice 
      if(click$group == "selected"){
        proxy %>% 
          clearGroup(group = "selected")
      } #END CONDITIONAL 

    }) #END OBSERVE EVENT

  }) #END SHINYAPP
```

In the above example, every clicked polygon turns red. If a previously-selected red polygon is clicked again, every red polygon is cleared from the map, leaving the initial white polygon renderings.

I can accomplish the desired selecting/deselecting effect when I'm working with only one polygon at a time by using the string layerId "selected" (commented out in the above code), but doing that removes my ability to select and highlight multiple polygons at the same time.

I'm open to any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer lies in layerIds. I wasn't understanding how these were applied to my polygons and removing shapes--understanding this is key. This might not be the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done!

In the below code, the initial map rendering of Rwanda has a `layerId` of `rwa@data$NAME_1`, which are the region names. You can see this in action with the `label` also being set as `rwa@data$NAME_1`. So in the below image, the leftmost polygon is labeled as Iburengerazuba, its attribute in the `NAME_1` column. **This layerId sets the `click$id` for any click events you have on this initial map rendering.** So, just as this polygon is labeled Iburengerazuba, its `click$id` will also be set as Iburengerazuba. [As stated in the Leaflet Shiny documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html), if you've got more than one polygon, this needs to be a vectorized argument. If you only need to select and deselect ONE polygon (so only one region at a time, in this example), you could use a `layerId` string, as I mentioned in my question (such as `layerId = "selected"`).

[image]

Next up is the `observeEvent` for your shape click. [Thanks to the help of user @John Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106547/how-to-save-click-events-in-leaflet-shiny-map), I figured out how to save all click events (click ids specifically in this case) made on the map. I saved those in a reactive vector, then subset my shapefile by those click ids. The code is pretty thoroughly commented, so hopefully anyone else looking for this same solution can figure out exactly what's going on.

The final bit of code (housed in the `if...else` conditional statement) is probably the most confusing. Let's look at the `else` portion of the code first. (Note: Your initial map click is going to trigger this event because there's no way for the `if` conditions to have been met upon first click.) If any white polygon is clicked, the `addPolygons()` call is triggered, adding the clicked polygon onto the map with different styling (in this case, it's red). **This is plotting an entirely different polygon on top of the `leafletProxy` object!**

[image]

**The key to removing the red clicked polygons is giving these polygons a different `layerId` than the initial map rendering.** Note that in the above image, the white polygon that was labeled Iburengerazuba is now labeled as 3. This is because the `layerId` in the second `addPolygons` call is set as `CC_1` INSTEAD OF `NAME_1`. So, bottom layer white map has a NAME_1 layerID and therefore NAME_1 click ids, whereas any red clicked polygon plotted on top of that has a CC_1 layerId and therefore CC_1 click ids.

The `if` statements states that if your `click$id` already exists in the `clickedPolys` polygon, that this shape is removed. This is kind of confusing, so again, it might help to go through each line of code and play around with it to truly understand.

Again using the above example, clicking the leftmost polygon adds the `layerId` Iburengerazuba to the `clickedIds$ids` vector. This click event triggers a second map drawing, plotting the clicked polygon on top of itself in a different style and with a `layerId` of 3 (from the `CC_1` column). We want to say that if any red polygon is clicked twice (`if(click$id %in% clickedPolys@data$CC_1)`), it counts as a deselection, and that polygon should be removed from the map. So if you click on the red leftmost polygon with a `layerId` of 3, the `clickedIds$ids` vector will be comprised of `Iburengerazuba` and `3`. Iburengerazuba in the `NAME_1` column of the `clickedPolys` polygon corresponds to 3 in the `CC_1` column, triggering the `if` statement. The call `removeShape(layerId = click$id)` means to remove the shape that corresponds to that click$id. So in this case, the `clickedPolys` polygon with a `CC_1` `layerId` of 3.

Keep in mind that *every* click id, both `NAME_1` and `CC_1` are being recorded in your `clickedIds$ids` vector. This vector is subsetting your Rwanda shapefile to map all clicked polygons, so as you're clicking polygons, the `clickedPolys` polygon is dynamically updating (use `print` calls to check every bit of code if this isn't making sense to you!). Removing any double-clicked shape isn't enough to plot everything correctly--**you need to remove deselected layerIds, both NAME_1 and CC_1, from the `clickedIds$ids` vector**. I matched each deselected `CC_1 layerId` to its corresponding `NAME_1` value and removed both of those attributes from the `clickedIds$ids` vector so that they are removed from the `clickedPolys` polygon.

Voila! Now you can select and deselect any polygons you want!

```
library(raster)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

#load shapefile
rwa <- getData("GADM", country = "RWA", level = 1)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("map")
  ), 
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    #create empty vector to hold all click ids
    clickedIds <- reactiveValues(ids = vector())
    
    #initial map output
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addPolygons(data = rwa, 
                    fillColor = "white", 
                    fillOpacity = 1, 
                    color = "black", 
                    stroke = T, 
                    weight = 1, 
                    layerId = rwa@data$NAME_1, 
                    group = "regions", 
                    label = rwa@data$NAME_1)
    }) #END RENDER LEAFLET
    
    observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
      
      #create object for clicked polygon
      click <- input$map_shape_click
      
      #define leaflet proxy for second regional level map
      proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
      
      #append all click ids in empty vector 
      clickedIds$ids <- c(clickedIds$ids, click$id)
      
      #shapefile with all clicked polygons - original shapefile subsetted by all admin names from the click list
      clickedPolys <- rwa[rwa@data$NAME_1 %in% clickedIds$ids, ]
      
      #if the current click ID [from CC_1] exists in the clicked polygon (if it has been clicked twice)
      if(click$id %in% clickedPolys@data$CC_1){
        
        #define vector that subsets NAME that matches CC_1 click ID
        nameMatch <- clickedPolys@data$NAME_1[clickedPolys@data$CC_1 == click$id]
        
        #remove the current click$id AND its name match from the clickedPolys shapefile
        clickedIds$ids <- clickedIds$ids[!clickedIds$ids %in% click$id] 
        clickedIds$ids <- clickedIds$ids[!clickedIds$ids %in% nameMatch]
        
        #remove that highlighted polygon from the map
        proxy %>% removeShape(layerId = click$id)
        
      } else {
        
        #map highlighted polygons
        proxy %>% addPolygons(data = clickedPolys,
                              fillColor = "red",
                              fillOpacity = 1,
                              weight = 1,
                              color = "black",
                              stroke = T,
                              label = clickedPolys@data$CC_1, 
                              layerId = clickedPolys@data$CC_1)
      } #END CONDITIONAL
    }) #END OBSERVE EVENT
  }) #END SHINYAPP
```

Comment: Thank you Lauren, for your excellent solution. However, when I click a second time in the same polygon (In order to deselect the polygon), the `click$id` value returns null. I don't know why is occurring this behaviour.

Comment: @SergioFernández could you post a code sample? Hard to diagnose without seeing your code!

Comment: Thank you Lauren, finally I understood it. But it's quite confusing you to use CCA_1 when it doesn't appear in the original data frame (from the shapefile). For my project to work, I had to create an additional column just with the same identifier but with a random string as a prefix. That did the job.

Comment: @SergioFernández this is a bit of an older example, so it's very possible that the CCA_1 column is no longer part of the imported Rwanda shapefile (pulled straight from GADM from the 'getData()' function) - but I assure you that it once was! Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Just a note. `CCA_1` doesn't seem to be there in the current version, but can be replaced with anything else. You can also convert to `sf` by getting rid of all the `@data` bits.

Comment: replacing `CCA_1` with `CC_1` in the above answer will make it work now.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65935636/9841389) you can find another approach to this.

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal! This original answer is 5(!) years old, so I'm glad that there are more straightforward options now :)