# Using reactiveValues() inside an observe function in Shiny Leaflet app causes infinite recursion

Tags: r, recursion, shiny, leaflet, infinite

I have a Shiny Leaflet app I'm working on that saves map click events with the use of `reactiveValues()` (that question was posted by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106547/how-to-save-click-events-in-leaflet-shiny-map)). When I use `observeEvent` for each click event on the map, the `reactiveValues` work perfectly.

In my full app code, it has become necessary to use `observe` instead of `observeEvent`. When I make this change from `observeEvent` to `observe`, the `reactiveValues` seem to cause infinite recursion. Here's some reproducible example code:

```
library(raster)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

#load shapefile
rwa <- getData("GADM", country = "RWA", level = 1)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("map")
  ), 

  server <- function(input, output, session){

    #create empty vector to hold all click ids
    clickedIds <- reactiveValues(ids = vector())

    #initial map output
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addPolygons(data = rwa, 
                    fillColor = "white", 
                    fillOpacity = 1, 
                    color = "black", 
                    stroke = T, 
                    weight = 1, 
                    layerId = rwa@data$OBJECTID, 
                    group = "regions")
    }) #END RENDER LEAFLET

    observe({

      #create object for clicked polygon
      click <- input$map_shape_click

      #append all click ids in empty vector
      clickedIds$ids <- c(clickedIds$ids, click$id)

      print(clickedIds$ids)
    }) #END OBSERVE EVENT
  }) #END SHINYAPP
```

I'm able to stop this by using `unique()` or `isolate()` in the following line of code:

```
  #append all click ids in empty vector
  clickedIds$ids <- c(unique(clickedIds$ids), click$id)
```

BUT in my full app, this (for whatever reason) slows the entire app and makes some visualizations clunky. I'm looking for some alternatives and ideally an explanation why `observe` causes infinite recursion whereas `observeEvent` does not.

Comment: I would expect infinite recursion here. `observe()` says, essentially, re-evaluate the expression I contain each time one of my reactive dependencies changes. When `clickedIds$ids` (a reactive dependency) is modified, that triggers evaluation of the contents of `observe()`; that evaluation itself modifies the value of `clickedIds$ids`, which in turn triggers another evaluation of the contents of `observe()`, which ........... infinite recursion.

Comment: As noted in `?observeEvent` (and, for example, near the end of the first example [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html)), `observeEvent()` evaluates the block of code to be executed in an `isolate()` environment, which is why you didn't get infinite recursion when using it.

Comment: You should post the working version as a solution (using the line `observeEvent(input$map_shape_click,{ ` instead of just `observe({`