# Turn states on a map into clickable objects in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the following Shiny Application:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)



shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Tweetminer",
      titleWidth = 350
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      width = 350,
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Menu Item")
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          tabPanel("Set tweets2", 
                   plotOutput('plot',
                              brush = brushOpts(
                                id = "plot1_brush"
                              )),
                   h4("Selected States"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("select_states"),
                   h4("Selected States' Tweets"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("tweets"),
                   h4("Selected States' Amount"),
                   textOutput("test1")#,
                   #actionButton("button", textOutput("test1"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { 

    output$plot <- renderPlot({

      all_states <- map_data("state") 
      states_positive <- c("louisiana", "alaska", "new york")

      # Plot results
      ggplot(all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) +
        geom_polygon(fill="grey", colour = "white") +
        geom_polygon(fill="orange", data = filter(all_states, region %in% states_positive)) 

    })

  })
```

This works. However I would like to include the functionality to click on a state and then get a pop up bar. I know how to do it click brush but there you often select multiple states. Any thoughts on how I can turn the states into clickable objects?

Comment: I don't have a coded or pseudocoded example, but what if you got the coordinates of the click and found the state in which those coordinates reside?  I'm not familiar with the maps package but it looks like latitude and longitude data are in there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Overview

Use `shiny::observeEvent( input$outputId_shape_click, {foo})` to monitor the leaflet map whenever a click occurs on a polygon. Then, store the list of clicked polygons as a reactive value to perform actions based on the polygon(s) in that list.

I called that object `click.list`, which was used to filter `comarea606` - the spatial polygon data frame - by those polygons stored in `click.list`. You would then go onto use that filtered data to perform subsequent operations.

## Reproducible Example

This Shiny app displays a leaflet map of the [City of Chicago's 77 community areas](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Community-Areas-current-/cauq-8yn6) (i.e. neighborhoods). When the user clicks on a particular community area, that polygon's border changes color. The Clear the Map button re-renders the leaflet map to take away the polygons that the user highlighted when clicking.

```
# install necessary packages
install.packages( pkgs = c( "devtools", "shiny", "shinydashboard" ) )
# install the development version of leaflet from Github
devtools::install_github( repo = "rstudio/leaflet" )


# load necessary packages
library( leaflet )    
library( shiny )
library( shinydashboard )


# import City of Chicago current community area boundaries
comarea606 <- readRDS( gzcon( url( description = "https://github.com/cenuno/shiny/raw/master/cps_locator/Data/raw-data/comarea606_raw.RDS" ) ) )
# Note: for speed, I loaded the GeoJSON file from the City's
#       data portal and exported the object as an RDS file in another script.
#       To download the raw data yourself, feel free to run this:
#       install.packages( pkgs = c( "sp", "rgdal" ) )
#       comarea606 <- 
#           rgdal::readOGR( dsn = "https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/geospatial/cauq-8yn6?method=export&format=GEOJSON"
#                              , layer = "OGRGeoJSON"
#                              , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
#                             ) 


# create the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # place the contents inside a box
  shinydashboard::box(
    width = 12
    , title = "Click on the map!"
    # separate the box by a column
    , column(
      width = 2
      , shiny::actionButton( inputId = "clearHighlight"
                             , icon = icon( name = "eraser")
                             , label = "Clear the Map"
                             , style = "color: #fff; background-color: #D75453; border-color: #C73232"
      )
    )
    # separate the box by a column
    , column(
      width = 10
      , leaflet::leafletOutput( outputId = "myMap"
                                , height = 850
      )
    )
  ) # end of the box
) # end of fluid page

# create the server
server <- function( input, output, session ){

  # create foundational map
  foundational.map <- shiny::reactive({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles( urlTemplate = "https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png") %>%
      setView( lng = -87.567215
               , lat = 41.822582
               , zoom = 11 ) %>%
      addPolygons( data = comarea606
                   , fillOpacity = 0
                   , opacity = 0.2
                   , color = "#000000"
                   , weight = 2
                   , layerId = comarea606$community
                   , group = "click.list"
      )
  })

  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({

    foundational.map()

  }) # end of leaflet::renderLeaflet({})

  # store the list of clicked polygons in a vector
  click.list <- shiny::reactiveValues( ids = vector() )

  # observe where the user clicks on the leaflet map
  # during the Shiny app session
  # Courtesy of two articles:
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953741/select-and-deselect-polylines-in-shiny-leaflet
  # https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html
  shiny::observeEvent( input$myMap_shape_click, {

    # store the click(s) over time
    click <- input$myMap_shape_click

    # store the polygon ids which are being clicked
    click.list$ids <- c( click.list$ids, click$id )

    # filter the spatial data frame
    # by only including polygons
    # which are stored in the click.list$ids object
    lines.of.interest <- comarea606[ which( comarea606$community %in% click.list$ids ) , ]

    # if statement
    if( is.null( click$id ) ){
      # check for required values, if true, then the issue
      # is "silent". See more at: ?req
      req( click$id )

    } else if( !click$id %in% lines.of.interest@data$id ){

      # call the leaflet proxy
      leaflet::leafletProxy( mapId = "myMap" ) %>%
        # and add the polygon lines
        # using the data stored from the lines.of.interest object
        addPolylines( data = lines.of.interest
                      , layerId = lines.of.interest@data$id
                      , color = "#6cb5bc"
                      , weight = 5
                      , opacity = 1
        ) 

    } # end of if else statement

  }) # end of shiny::observeEvent({})


  # Create the logic for the "Clear the map" action button
  # which will clear the map of all user-created highlights
  # and display a clean version of the leaflet map
  shiny::observeEvent( input$clearHighlight, {

    # recreate $myMap
    output$myMap <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({

      # first
      # set the reactive value of click.list$ids to NULL
      click.list$ids <- NULL

      # second
      # recall the foundational.map() object
      foundational.map()

    }) # end of re-rendering $myMap

  }) # end of clearHighlight action button logic

} # end of server

## run shinyApp ##
shiny::shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server)

# end of script #
```

## References

[Select and Deselect Polylines in Shiny/Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953741/select-and-deselect-polylines-in-shiny-leaflet) and the [Inputs/Events](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) section of the *Using Leaflet with Shiny page within the Leaflet for R website* were helpful in producing this example.

## Session Info

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] leaflet_1.1.0.9000   shinydashboard_0.6.1 shiny_1.0.5         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] htmlwidgets_1.0 compiler_3.4.3  magrittr_1.5    R6_2.2.2       
 [5] htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.3     yaml_2.1.16     Rcpp_0.12.15   
 [9] crosstalk_1.0.0 digest_0.6.14   xtable_1.8-2    httpuv_1.3.5   
[13] mime_0.5
```

## RStudio Version

```
$citation

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2016). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio,
  Inc., Boston, MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2016},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.1.414’
```