# Select multiple items using map_click in leaflet, linked to selectizeInput() in shiny app (R)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-sf, r-leaflet

I would like to create a leaflet map where you can select multiple polygons and this will update the `selectizeInput()` in a shiny app. This would including removing a selected polygon, when it is removed in the `selectizeInput()`.

I have slightly changed/updated [the code from the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104576/changing-styles-when-selecting-and-deselecting-multiple-polygons-with-leaflet-sh) (use of sf instead of sp and more dplyr where I could work out what the base R was).

The polygons could probably be updated with an `observeEvent` tied in with `input$clicked_locations`, but not sure exactly how.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

#load shapefile
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  st_transform(4326)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    "Update selectize input by clicking on the map",
    
    leafletOutput("map"),
    "I would like the selectize input to update to show all the locations clicked,",
    "but also when items are removed here, they are removed on the map too, so linked to the map.",
    selectizeInput(inputId = "clicked_locations",
                   label = "Clicked",
                   choices = nc$NAME,
                   selected = NULL,
                   multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    #create empty vector to hold all click ids
    clicked_ids <- reactiveValues(ids = vector())
    
    #initial map output
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc,
                    fillColor = "white",
                    fillOpacity = 0.5,
                    color = "black",
                    stroke = TRUE,
                    weight = 1,
                    layerId = ~NAME,
                    group = "regions",
                    label = ~NAME)
    }) #END RENDER LEAFLET
    
    observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
      
      #create object for clicked polygon
      click <- input$map_shape_click
      
      #define leaflet proxy for second regional level map
      proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
      
      #append all click ids in empty vector
      clicked_ids$ids <- c(clicked_ids$ids, click$id) # name when clicked, id when unclicked
      
      #shapefile with all clicked polygons - original shapefile subsetted by all admin names from the click list
      clicked_polys <- nc %>%
        filter(NAME %in% clicked_ids$ids)
      
      #if the current click ID [from CNTY_ID] exists in the clicked polygon (if it has been clicked twice)
      if(click$id %in% clicked_polys$CNTY_ID){
        
        #define vector that subsets NAME that matches CNTY_ID click ID - needs to be different to above
        name_match <- clicked_polys$NAME[clicked_polys$CNTY_ID == click$id]
        
        #remove the current click$id AND its name match from the clicked_polys shapefile
        clicked_ids$ids <- clicked_ids$ids[!clicked_ids$ids %in% click$id]
        clicked_ids$ids <- clicked_ids$ids[!clicked_ids$ids %in% name_match]
        
        # just to see
        print(clicked_ids$ids)
        
        # update
        updateSelectizeInput(session,
                             inputId = "clicked_locations",
                             label = "",
                             choices = nc$NAME,
                             selected = clicked_ids$ids)
        
        #remove that highlighted polygon from the map
        proxy %>% removeShape(layerId = click$id)
        
      } else {
        
        #map highlighted polygons
        proxy %>% addPolygons(data = clicked_polys,
                              fillColor = "red",
                              fillOpacity = 0.5,
                              weight = 1,
                              color = "black",
                              stroke = TRUE,
                              layerId = clicked_polys$CNTY_ID)
        
        # just to see
        print(clicked_ids$ids)
        
        # update
        updateSelectizeInput(session,
                             inputId = "clicked_locations",
                             label = "",
                             choices = nc$NAME,
                             selected = clicked_ids$ids)
        
      } #END CONDITIONAL
    }) #END OBSERVE EVENT
  }) #END SHINYAPP
```

This is also posted [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/select-multiple-items-using-map-click-in-leaflet-linked-to-selectizeinput-in-shiny-app/93752) where you can also find the edited version of the code from the answer (originally an `sp` dataset), that works. This code for the `nc` data set seems to be the same to me, but doesn't seem to work, although updating the polygons based on the `selectizeInput()` isn't in there.

Any ideas on this?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please see the following workaround:

I'm adding all polygons on rendering the map and hiding the red overlay. Furthermore each of the red polygons is assigned to it's own group. On click the according group and therefore the polygon is shown/hidden.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

#load shapefile
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  st_transform(4326)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    "Update selectize input by clicking on the map",
    
    leafletOutput("map"),
    "I would like the selectize input to update to show all the locations selected,",
    "but also when items are removed here, they are removed on the map too, so linked to the map.",
    selectizeInput(inputId = "selected_locations",
                   label = "Selected:",
                   choices = nc$NAME,
                   selected = NULL,
                   multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    #create empty vector to hold all click ids
    selected_ids <- reactiveValues(ids = vector())
    
    #initial map output
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc,
                    fillColor = "white",
                    fillOpacity = 0.5,
                    color = "black",
                    stroke = TRUE,
                    weight = 1,
                    layerId = ~NAME,
                    group = "regions",
                    label = ~NAME) %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc,
                    fillColor = "red",
                    fillOpacity = 0.5,
                    weight = 1,
                    color = "black",
                    stroke = TRUE,
                    layerId = ~CNTY_ID,
                    group = ~NAME) %>%
        hideGroup(group = nc$NAME) # nc$CNTY_ID
    }) #END RENDER LEAFLET
    
    #define leaflet proxy for second regional level map
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
    
    #create empty vector to hold all click ids
    selected <- reactiveValues(groups = vector())
    
    observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
      if(input$map_shape_click$group == "regions"){
        selected$groups <- c(selected$groups, input$map_shape_click$id)
        proxy %>% showGroup(group = input$map_shape_click$id)
      } else {
        selected$groups <- setdiff(selected$groups, input$map_shape_click$group)
        proxy %>% hideGroup(group = input$map_shape_click$group)
      }
      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           inputId = "selected_locations",
                           choices = nc$NAME,
                           selected = selected$groups)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$selected_locations, {
      removed_via_selectInput <- setdiff(selected$groups, input$selected_locations)
      added_via_selectInput <- setdiff(input$selected_locations, selected$groups)
      
      if(length(removed_via_selectInput) > 0){
        selected$groups <- input$selected_locations
        proxy %>% hideGroup(group = removed_via_selectInput)
      }
      
      if(length(added_via_selectInput) > 0){
        selected$groups <- input$selected_locations
        proxy %>% showGroup(group = added_via_selectInput)
      }
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
  })
```

[image: result]

---

**Edit:** regarding your initial approach adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104576/changing-styles-when-selecting-and-deselecting-multiple-polygons-with-leaflet-sh) you would need to pass the `layerId` as `character` to make things work again:

```
    proxy %>% removeShape(layerId = as.character(click$id))
    
    proxy %>% addPolygons(data = clicked_polys,
                          fillColor = "red",
                          fillOpacity = 0.5,
                          weight = 1,
                          color = "black",
                          stroke = TRUE,
                          layerId = as.character(clicked_polys$CNTY_ID))
```

I filed an [issue regarding this](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/724).

However, I'd still prefer the above show/hide approach as I guess it's more performant than adding and removing polygons.

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks. I'll add the bounty as well when I am allowed to.

Comment: One note, you can delete all of the items from the selectizeInput (rather than unclicking), but the last polygon stays on the map.

Comment: Ah I see - we need to set `ignoreNULL = FALSE` for the selectize observer otherwise the last deletion is ignored. Please see my edit. Cheers

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ismirsehregal , how would you change the code if you have just the markers instead of polygons ? would be great if you could check this out : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72577523/select-and-highlight-multiple-point-on-the-map-on-leaflet-in-shiny-app`

Comment: @user9112767 please see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70200278/r-shiny-with-leaflet-change-color-of-marker-after-click/70258699#70258699).