# Select multiple items using map_click in leaflet, linked to selectizeInput() in shiny app (R) based on filtered data

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm creating a shiny app (my first ever) that uses the solution offered by ismirsehregal to (de)select multiple items using map_click and `selectizeInput`.  [Select multiple items using map_click in leaflet, linked to selectizeInput() in shiny app (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893124/select-multiple-items-using-map-click-in-leaflet-linked-to-selectizeinput-in)

But now I would like to add a `pickerInput` to first filter the map.  So, let's say users can first filter the nc dataset based on "SID79" (something like the below).

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

#load shapefile
nc_raw <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  st_transform(4326)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    # I added pickerinput to filter based on SID79
    pickerInput("select_type",
                label = "Select Type",
                choices = sort(unique(nc_raw$SID79)), 
                options = list("actions-box" = TRUE), 
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = 1),
    
    "Update selectize input by clicking on the map",
    
    leafletOutput("map"),
    # I would like the selectize input to update to show all the locations selected by pickerInput,
    # when items are removed here, they are removed on the map too, so linked to the map. 
    # Also users can add areas that are initially deselected due to the pickerInput filter
    
    selectizeInput(inputId = "selected_locations",
                   label = "selected",
                   choices = " ",
                   selected = NULL,
                   multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    ##### Filter regions ####
    nc <- reactive({
      nc  <- filter(nc_raw, 
                    SID79 %in% input$select_type) 
    })
    
    #create empty vector to hold all click ids
    selected_ids <- reactiveValues(ids = vector())
    
    #initial map output
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc_raw,
                    fillColor = "white",
                    fillOpacity = 0.5,
                    color = "black",
                    stroke = TRUE,
                    weight = 1,
                    layerId = ~NAME,
                    group = "regions",
                    label = ~NAME) %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc(),
                    fillColor = "red",
                    fillOpacity = 0.5,
                    weight = 1,
                    color = "black",
                    stroke = TRUE,
                    layerId = ~CNTY_ID,
                    group = ~NAME) %>%
        
        # I modified this from hideGroup; Ideally users could still add areas filtered out by
        # pickerInput but not sure the best way to do this... another map layer?
        showGroup(group = nc()$NAME)
    }) #END RENDER LEAFLET
    
    #define leaflet proxy for second regional level map
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
    
    # create empty vector to hold all click ids
    # selected should initially display all areas selected by pickerInput
    selected <- reactiveValues(groups = vector())
    
    observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
      if(input$map_shape_click$group == "regions"){
        selected$groups <- c(selected$groups, input$map_shape_click$id)
        proxy %>% showGroup(group = input$map_shape_click$id)
      } else {
        selected$groups <- setdiff(selected$groups, input$map_shape_click$group)
        proxy %>% hideGroup(group = input$map_shape_click$group)
      }
      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           inputId = "selected_locations",
                           label = "",
                           choices = nc()$NAME,
                           selected = selected$groups)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$selected_locations, {
      removed_via_selectInput <- setdiff(selected$groups, input$selected_locations)
      added_via_selectInput <- setdiff(input$selected_locations, selected$groups)
      
      if(length(removed_via_selectInput) > 0){
        selected$groups <- input$selected_locations
        proxy %>% hideGroup(group = removed_via_selectInput)
      }
      
      if(length(added_via_selectInput) > 0){
        selected$groups <- input$selected_locations
        proxy %>% showGroup(group = added_via_selectInput)
      }
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
  })
```

Now the map should update based on select_type filters and populate the `selectizeInput` display as well. From there, users should be able to add or delete areas by clicking on the map or using `selectizeInput`. Here is a picture of my app and how I would like this functionality to work:

[image: result]

Any help would be much appreciated! I've been tweaking ismirsehregal's code for hours and cannot get this to work. It's too complicated for me to make this seemingly simple modification.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please provide us with a [reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help).

Comment: Thanks for the edits. It's my first post!  I added a repro.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I left an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add another `observeEvent` tracking the reactive `nc()` to update  the choices of `selectizeInput` "selected_locations".

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

#load shapefile
nc_raw <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  st_transform(4326)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    pickerInput("select_type",
                label = "Select Type",
                choices = sort(unique(nc_raw$SID79)), 
                options = list("actions-box" = TRUE), 
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = 1),
    "Update selectize input by clicking on the map",
    leafletOutput("map"),
    "I would like the selectize input to update to show all the locations selected,",
    "but also when items are removed here, they are removed on the map too, so linked to the map.",
    selectizeInput(inputId = "selected_locations",
                   label = "Selected:",
                   choices = NULL,
                   selected = NULL,
                   multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    ##### Filter regions ####
    nc <- reactive({
      filter(nc_raw, SID79 %in% input$select_type) 
    })
    
    observeEvent(nc(), {
      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           inputId = "selected_locations",
                           choices = nc()$NAME,
                           selected = input$selected_locations)
    })
    
    #create empty vector to hold all click ids
    selected_ids <- reactiveValues(ids = vector())
    
    #initial map output
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      req({NROW(nc()) > 0})
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc(),
                    fillColor = "white",
                    fillOpacity = 0.5,
                    color = "black",
                    stroke = TRUE,
                    weight = 1,
                    layerId = ~NAME,
                    group = "regions",
                    label = ~NAME) %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc(),
                    fillColor = "red",
                    fillOpacity = 0.5,
                    weight = 1,
                    color = "black",
                    stroke = TRUE,
                    layerId = ~CNTY_ID,
                    group = ~NAME) %>%
        hideGroup(group = setdiff(nc()$NAME, input$selected_locations)) # nc()$CNTY_ID
    }) #END RENDER LEAFLET
    
    #define leaflet proxy for second regional level map
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
    
    #create empty vector to hold all click ids
    selected <- reactiveValues(groups = vector())
    
    observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
      if(input$map_shape_click$group == "regions"){
        selected$groups <- c(selected$groups, input$map_shape_click$id)
        proxy %>% showGroup(group = input$map_shape_click$id)
      } else {
        selected$groups <- setdiff(selected$groups, input$map_shape_click$group)
        proxy %>% hideGroup(group = input$map_shape_click$group)
      }
      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           inputId = "selected_locations",
                           choices = nc()$NAME,
                           selected = selected$groups)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$selected_locations, {
      removed_via_selectInput <- setdiff(selected$groups, input$selected_locations)
      added_via_selectInput <- setdiff(input$selected_locations, selected$groups)
      
      if(length(removed_via_selectInput) > 0){
        selected$groups <- input$selected_locations
        proxy %>% hideGroup(group = removed_via_selectInput)
      }
      
      if(length(added_via_selectInput) > 0){
        selected$groups <- input$selected_locations
        proxy %>% showGroup(group = added_via_selectInput)
      }
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
  })
```

[image: result]

---

**Edit: OPs additional request, deselect groups:**

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

#load shapefile
nc_raw <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  st_transform(4326)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    pickerInput("select_type",
                label = "Select Type",
                choices = sort(unique(nc_raw$SID79)), 
                options = list("actions-box" = TRUE), 
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = 1),
    "Update selectize input by clicking on the map",
    leafletOutput("map"),
    "I would like the selectize input to update to show all the locations selected,",
    "but also when items are removed here, they are removed on the map too, so linked to the map.",
    selectizeInput(inputId = "selected_locations",
                   label = "Selected:",
                   choices = NULL,
                   selected = NULL,
                   multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    ##### Filter regions ####
    nc <- reactive({
      filter(nc_raw, SID79 %in% input$select_type) 
    })
    
    observeEvent(nc(), {
      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           inputId = "selected_locations",
                           choices = nc()$NAME,
                           selected = nc()$NAME) # input$selected_locations
    })
    
    #create empty vector to hold all click ids
    selected_ids <- reactiveValues(ids = vector())
    
    #initial map output
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      req({NROW(nc()) > 0})
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc(),
                    fillColor = "white",
                    fillOpacity = 0.5,
                    color = "black",
                    stroke = TRUE,
                    weight = 1,
                    layerId = ~NAME,
                    group = "regions",
                    label = ~NAME) %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc(),
                    fillColor = "red",
                    fillOpacity = 0.5,
                    weight = 1,
                    color = "black",
                    stroke = TRUE,
                    layerId = ~CNTY_ID,
                    group = ~NAME) 
      # %>% hideGroup(group = setdiff(nc()$NAME, input$selected_locations)) # nc()$CNTY_ID
    }) #END RENDER LEAFLET
    
    #define leaflet proxy for second regional level map
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
    
    #create empty vector to hold all click ids
    selected <- reactiveValues(groups = vector())
    
    observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
      if(input$map_shape_click$group == "regions"){
        selected$groups <- c(selected$groups, input$map_shape_click$id)
        proxy %>% showGroup(group = input$map_shape_click$id)
      } else {
        selected$groups <- setdiff(selected$groups, input$map_shape_click$group)
        proxy %>% hideGroup(group = input$map_shape_click$group)
      }
      updateSelectizeInput(session,
                           inputId = "selected_locations",
                           choices = nc()$NAME,
                           selected = selected$groups)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$selected_locations, {
      removed_via_selectInput <- setdiff(selected$groups, input$selected_locations)
      added_via_selectInput <- setdiff(input$selected_locations, selected$groups)
      
      if(length(removed_via_selectInput) > 0){
        selected$groups <- input$selected_locations
        proxy %>% hideGroup(group = removed_via_selectInput)
      }
      
      if(length(added_via_selectInput) > 0){
        selected$groups <- input$selected_locations
        proxy %>% showGroup(group = added_via_selectInput)
      }
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
  })
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is wonderful. Might  it be possible to make the following (small?) adjustment: Areas selected by SID79 filter are initially highlighted in red and appear in the "Selected" box. We can then click on the map to deselect an area (or we can just delete from the "Selected" list). So instead of clicking on the areas to select them, they are already selected by the "SID79" filter and we click to deselect.  So, the screenshot I included in the original post is the initial view after the regional filter is selected (prior to making any selections on the map or selection box).

Comment: Thank you, @ismirsehregal! This is exactly the functionality I was hoping for... it works perfectly. Appreciate your patience (and guidance) with my first attempt to post!